# When embedding a playlist, can I show the list of videos instead of the first video?

Tags: youtube, embed, playlist, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to embed a youtube playlist onto a landing page next to another youtube video. However, I can only get to the list of videos in the playlist when clicking on the "playlist" button. Is there any way to have this list appear right away, instead of the first video in the playlist? It looks horrible from a design standpoint and I'm worried people won't understand it's a playlist, since "playlist" appears in such tiny letters.

Thanks!